# Concatenate strings - convenience wrapper?

Tags: r, string

Is there a package that would extend the `+` operator with method for `character` types ( i.e. `` `+.character` <-function(x,y) {...} `` )?

In base `R`, writing this yields error:

```
"a" + "b"
# Error in "a" + "b" : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

What I would like to achieve is:

```
"a" + "b"
#"ab"
```

I am aware of `paste0("a","b")`, but `"a" + "b"` is arguably more readable/shorter.

Of course there is always possibility to define [special binary operator](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html):

```
`%+%` <- function(x,y) paste0(x,y)

"foo" %+% "bar" %+% "baz"
# "foobarbaz"
```

Comment: `character` is a special class (it's also a type). It looks like `+` is hardcoded to give this error for character input and never calls the method in such a case.

Answer (score 1):

[`stringi`](http://www.rexamine.com/resources/stringi/) provides `%s+%` operator:

```
> library(stringi)
> "a" %s+% "b"
[1] "ab"
```

and `%stri+%` operator:

```
> "a" %stri+% "b"
[1] "ab"
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to improve the readability of your code, you may enhance base `+` function so it would work like in Python:

```
"+" <- function(x, y) {
         if(is.character(x) || is.character(y)) {
                 return(paste(x, y, sep = ""))
         } else {
                 .Primitive("+")(x, y)
         }
}

"a" + "b"
[1] "ab"
```